# Angularjs twitter login

Tags: angularjs, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I working on an angularjs SPA(single page appication) application,In this Application I need to provide FB and twitter login, I am dine with facebook login via this library :

https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook

But for Twitter I am not finding exact way to provide log-in into angualrjs app,I googled a lot and found some libraries like ionic but some are paid library and some of them I did,nt get any call back after login to fetch access token and all other info This is the library which provides some social logins with angular but no call-back after login

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer.
is there any solution to achieve twitter login in angularjs?

Comment: Have you examined some server side solution to achieve oauth login?

Comment: I want to give it to angularjs side, Its client's requirement actually..

Comment: I have rest side with no UI in java and login should be done at angularjs side

Comment: Check the demo same I want

https://satellizer.herokuapp.com/#/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another and latest way to integrate twitter login through Digits

First crete app id using fabric

https://dev.twitter.com/

and follow integrate twitter as described here :
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/web/digits
Thanks for all help

Comment: If you need an angular wrapper for this, I've created https://github.com/ajwhite/angular-digits that let's you configure and utilize the Digits sdk nicely within your Angular project